# Best way to cool down the house in the summer

Tags: air-quality

Should I close all windows during the day and then open again at night so I get cooler air going through the house?

Comment: Too broad, too many variables too possibly answer.  Construction methods and insulation installed play a part in the answer.

Comment: Realize that some of the temperature rise inside the house is due to heat generated *inside* the house--all electrical devices generate waste heat, all warm blooded animals inside (human and non-human) are sources of heat. Closing up the house will prevent that heat from flowing to the outside.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes if your area cools down significantly at night. The other factor to study is if your inside temperature stays lower than the outside temp, when all closed up, during the hottest part of the day.

If cooler then closing up is the right strategy. If the inside approaches the outside temp then opening up and using fans to create air movement may be a reasonable strategy to pursue.

Of course these comments apply when you have no auxiliary cooling going on during the hot days.